# Show the : character in the timezone offset using datetime.strftime

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, timezone-offset

What is the format string to give to `strftime` which would give the same output as I see for `isoformat(' ')`?

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> import pytz 
>>> dt = datetime.now(tz=pytz.UTC).replace(microsecond=0)
>>> print dt
2014-05-29 13:11:00+00:00
>>> dt.isoformat(' ')
'2014-05-29 13:11:00+00:00'
>>> dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z')
'2014-05-29 13:11:00+0000'
```

Where does the `__str__` behaviour of datetime get that extra colon in the offset from?  I looked in the [formatting options](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) and could only find %z and %Z for +HHMM or name respectively.

I looked at the implementation of `datetime.__str__` but got no hints, it just says `pass` (?!).  I think it eventually delegates to `isoformat(' ')` but I don't understand how/where that is implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Datetime is implemented in C. There you find that the function for `tp_str`, which is used by Pythons `str` by default, just calls `isoformat()`.

Further the `datetime.strftime` method calls the libc `strftime` function, which gives the timezone difference without a seperator, whereas `datetime.isoformat` calls a method, which is implemented for Python directly, where a separator can be passed, which is the colon in this case.