# Formatting DateTimeField in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

When saving timestamp in Django's `DateTimeField` using `auto_now_add` this way:

```
creation_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

the field is saved with miliseconds:

```
2018-11-20T15:58:44.767594-06:00
```

I want to format this to be displayed without miliseconds:

```
2018-11-20T15:58:44-06:00
```

But the only option I could come up with does not exactly show what I need:

`format="%Y.%m.%dT%H:%M:%S%z"` gives me `2018.11.20T15:58:44-0600`
How do I format this field the way I need?

Alternatively I'd rather save `DateTimeField` without milliseconds at all but does `auto_now_add` allow to do this sort of thing?

Comment: From the date format "2018-11-20T15:58:44-06:00", is the "T" removeable or replaceable with space?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can override `DateTimeField`'s `value_to_string` method and add the changes there. For example:

```
class CustomDateTimeField(models.DateTimeField):
    def value_to_string(self, obj):
        val = self.value_from_object(obj)
        if val:
            val.replace(microsecond=0)
            return val.isoformat()
        return ''
```

And use it in model:

```
 created = CustomDateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Answer (score 9):

If you want to format it on when displaying it, you can use: `creation_timestamp.strftime("%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S")`

You can also make `DateTimeField` to save it in that format, but this would request a set of changes which will apply system wide:

In your settings file set the follwing:

1. `DATETIME_FORMAT="%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S"`
2. `L10N=False` to make sore localization data doesn't take precedent when it comes to dates format.
3. `USE_TZ=False`

But, consider the fact that this changes will apply by default to **all** date time objects from your project.

Comment: Key thing here is that I want to preserve timezone. But your answer contains only date and time

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to use isoformat. Look at that answer:

[Show the : character in the timezone offset using datetime.strftime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23934319/show-the-character-in-the-timezone-offset-using-datetime-strftime)

Answer (score 0):

I use pandas to_datetime() function to convert the time to string format.

```
import pandas as pd
record_list = myModel.objects.all()
for idx, record in enumerate(record_list ):
    st = str(pd.to_datetime(record.start_time))
    record_list[idx].start_time = st
```